# How know when Zone.js runs and where it has been triggered for debug purpose?

Tags: angular, zone.js

I work on an Angular application which use several third party libraries (leaflet/wijmo/d3/..).

For performances, I already use `cdRef.OnPush` almost everywhere.

And to prevent too many Zone runs, I use `zone.runOutsideAngular()` inside some specific components but I've seen some weird behaviors and would like to understand more when and from where (in MY code) Zone is triggered.

Do you know a way to log this?

[`angular@5.2.3` & `zone.js@0.8.19`]

Comment: Not sure about your question, but maybe this is a good read on the topic: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html

Comment: thanks I've already read it but that's not what I want. I would like to log when it's triggered and from where to debug an app.

Comment: what do you mean Zone is  triggered?

Comment: @jialipassion I mean when and what async code has been detected by Zone, which tell to Angular to run change detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NgZone.onStable

```
@Component {
  ...
} 
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (private ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.ngZone.onStable.subscribe(() => {console.log('zone stableed')});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using `onStable` & `onUnstable` observables, I got what I wanted but find where it come from in my code is not an easy task! :)